# Override margin settings of revtex4

Tags: tables, margins, geometry, revtex, ltablex

I would like to modify the left and right margins around the table in the following "code":

```
\documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps,unsortedaddress]{revtex4}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{-3.0cm}
\setlength\LTright{-2.0cm}

\scriptsize
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lr@{--}p{1.3cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.6cm}p{1.25cm}p{1.25cm}p{1.25cm}p{1.25cm}p{2.1cm}p{0.7cm}}
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj \\  
 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbb & ccc & ddd & eee & fff & ggg & hhh & iii & jjj
\end{tabularx}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

However, commands `\setlength\LTleft`, `\setlength\LTright`, and `\scriptsize` are ignored by `revtex4`. If `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}` is used instead of `\documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps,unsortedaddress]{revtex4}`, then the former three commands work fine. Could you please help me how to obtain the same output with `\documentclass[a4paper,preprint,aps,unsortedaddress]{revtex4}` as with `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}`? I am also curious how to use the same font size in `revtex4` as in the case of `article`.

Comment: IIRC, \LTleft and \LTright are from longtable.  The usual approach is to use \hspace*{-3cm} before and \hspace*{-2cm} after tabularx (box)..

Comment: What do you mean by "tabularx (box)"? Where to insert the \hspace*{-3cm} and \hspace*{-2cm}  statements? Could you please report the solution?

Comment: Do you mean "\hspace*{-3cm}\begin{tabularx}..." and "\end{tabularx}\hspace*{-2cm}"?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed with respect to the margins... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89629/discussion-between-john-kormylo-and-roloka).

Comment: Aha, the problem is tabularx, which you shouldn't use without at least one X column anyway. Just replace it with tabular and lose the {\linewidth}.

Comment: Is there any way to replace one p column with X without any change in the output?

Comment: The X column will be just wide enough to fit into \linewidth, in which case you won't need to change the margins.  (You might need \noindent.)